# Why does 'example.com.com' have an MX record?

Tags: php, validation, dns, mx-record

On PHP, running `checkdnsrr('example.com.com', 'MX')` returns 1 - I had expected it to return '0'. Replace 'example' with anything, and you get the same result.

Does that mean that cnet (who apparently own the com.com domain) receive any emails sent to somebody@example.com.com?

I'm interested because I am validating emails, and this has come up as a bug during the validation process.

---

This question has some useful information that seems to be relevant here:
[Using MX records to validate email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976712/using-mx-records-to-validate-email-addresses)

Comment: Did you try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php ??

Comment: @rkosegi I didn't. I'm using an API which calls `checkdnsrr()`. I could make the call to `getmxrr()` myself, though - I'll check.

Comment: On background both functions calls same code, but please check forum under description, it can be useful for you.

Comment: @rkosegi - Thanks, yes that is useful. Looks like calling `getmxrr()` may be the best option.

Comment: What on the earth did this question under PHP tag?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I wasn't sure whether this was a bug in the `checkdnsrr()` function, or something to do with the nature of MX records.

Answer (score 0):

I believe example.org is setup for "testing", rather than example.com.com - that's the same as using anyone elses domain for testing.

Comment: example.com and example.org are free to use for documentation purposes, but if your DNS server does not cache failures I'm not sure doing load testing against their (existing) DNS would be appreciated :) http://www.iana.org/domains/example/

Comment: @Sparx you can replace 'example' with anything and you get the same result. In other words, *.com.com returns true when checking for an MX record.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm interested because I am validating emails, and this has come up as a bug during the validation process.

Such an excellent example makes perfectly clear that the very idea of validating emails by whatever action other than actual sending a letter to given address is utterly wrong.

Comment: Do you mean 'try sending the email to the address'?