# Validate e-mail address with mx record validation in javascript/Angular/Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, email-validation

Is there a way to validate an e-mail address using mx record validation in javascript? For example I see that there is a PHP function for that (checkdnsrr) but my implementation is in Javascript/angular/Ionic and I cannot find a way to do this

Comment: ok thank you. please post your comment as an answer too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976712/using-mx-records-to-validate-email-addresses

Comment: @MatzReckeweg I don't use PHP like the one who asks the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a webservice for that. Create a small service that validates through mx validation and return the result to js